Android Studio Emulators List: Displays an error as an emulator
i'm currently working on a flutter project with Android Studio - Windows 11 x64, and there is something that is bothering me.
IMAGE OF THE EMULATOR ERROR
As you can see in the image, there is an extra emulator that displays itself as an ERROR.
This is the message i get if i press that emulator (user was redacted):
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\[USER]\.android\avd\
INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 18868.ini for reading.

WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\[USER]\.android\avd\
INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 18868.ini for reading. (2x) WARNING | Failed to process .ini file (null)\config.ini for reading.

WARNING | Failed to process .ini file (null)\config.ini for reading.

WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\[USER]\.android\avd\
INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 18868.ini for reading.

WARNING | Failed to process .ini file (null)\config.ini for reading.

WARNING | Failed to process .ini file (null)\config.ini for reading.

WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\[USER]\.android\avd\
INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 18868.ini for reading.

WARNING | Failed to process .ini file (null)\config.ini for reading.

WARNING | Failed to process .ini file (null)\config.ini for reading.

WARNING | emulator has searched the above paths but found no valid sdk root directory. PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path.
Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT 

INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 18776 

INFO | Android emulator version 34.1.20.0 (build_id 11610631) (CL:N/A)
INFO | AVD INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 18868 has path empty.

INFO | trying to check whether C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk is a valid sdk root.

Take note that the logs create the files but they are empty
The Pixel 7a emu works flawlessly, so it is more of a visual bug than a IDE breaking one.
I already tried uninstalling/installing everything (ANDROID STUDIO, SDKs, FLUTTER, DART), removing env variables, deleting %appdata% files, etc.
Has this issue happened to any of you before? and how did you solve it?
Thanks in advance!
